# store several git repos in one github repo

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, multiple-repositories

I have several git repositories with separate histories (versionning, branches). I want :

- that these projects still have separate histories
- to store them into a single github repository (in an existing organization)

I've studied submodules, but I understood that if a single github repository has several submodules, each submodule still need to reference a main repository elsewhere, so it does not solve the problem.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: You can use [orphan branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/1.7.3.1#git-checkout---orphan) to keep separate histories.

Comment: Have you looked at `git subtree`?